# Use await with react-native

Tags: javascript, react-native

I want to call a function asynchronously. I wrote the functions code in MyClass

```
static currentPassword(){
    OtherClass.getPassword().then((data) => {
      alert(JSON.stringify(data)); // this works fine
      return 'test';  // will return data.password at the end
      });
  }
```

In the same class I am creating this function

```
static async requestUser(){
      const token = await MyClass.currentPassword(); // this call the function successfully 
      alert(token); // this print 'undifined'
}
```

In requestUser `currentPassword()` is called but the return value is undefined

Answer (score 0):

You have to return the promise which returns 'test'.

```
static currentPassword(){
  return OtherClass.getPassword().then((data) => {
    alert(JSON.stringify(data));
    return 'test';
  });
}
```